# mysql calculate data between a certain times period within certain dates

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to calculate data within specific times of the day for a certain period?

I have a large set of data and want to calculate the "Amount" collected between certain time of the day for a specific period.

For example: Below, I want to sum the amount collected between 00:00 - 14:59 as 'Amount 1' and amount collected between 15:00 - 20:59 as 'Amount 2' from the 1st of July to the 31st of July. 'Total Amount' = 'Amount 1' + 'Amount 2'

sum(if(Date between '2012-07-01 00:00:00' and '2012-07-31 14:59:00',(Amount),0)) as 'Amount 1',
sum(if(Date between '2012-07-01 15:00:00' and '2012-07-31 20:59:00',(Amount),0)) as 'Amount 2',
sum(Amount) as 'Total Amount'

However, the result for 'Total Amount' does not match 'Amount 1'+'Amount 2'.

Comment: The difference between `Amount1+Amount2` and `TotalAmount` is caused by rows which are *neither* within the first *nor* the second date range. You are aware that the two ranges overlap significantly, right? You should probably clamp the *dates* with a `WHERE` clause and the *times* within the `IF()` constructs.

Comment: Thanks Jensgram!
Since the date column contains both date and time, had to use the TIME() function and specified the dates in the "Where" clause. There are still some discrepancies, but will try to figure it out.
sum(if((Time(DATE) between '15:00:00' and '20:59:00',(Amount),0)) as 'Amount 1'

Comment: However, facing another problem! When I use Time between '00:00:00' - '14:59:59' and '15:00:00' and '20:59:59', it works. But If I change the time to show amount between '21:00:00'-'14:59:59'(next day) and '15:00:00' -'20:59:59', 'Amount 1' does not return any value. Here's the query: SELECT CUSTOMER ID,
NAME,
sum(if(Time(DATE) between '21:00:00' and '14:59:59',(Amount),0)) as 'Amount 1',
sum(if(Time(DATE) between '15:00:00' and '20:59:59',(Amount),0)) as 'Amount 2',
sum(Amount) as 'Total Amount'

FROM CUSTOMER_DATABASE
WHERE DATE between '2012-07-01' and '2012-07-31'
group by 1
order by 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not putting any restrictions on your total amount field (i.e. no date or time restrictions, so data outside your date/time ranges is being included. You could either add conditional logic to your sum(Amount) like you did for the other fields or add a WHERE clause like this:

```
WHERE DATE(Amount) BETWEEN '2012-07-01' and '2012-07-31'
AND TIME(Amount) BETWEEN '00:00:00' and '20:59:00'
```

This would allow your Total Amount to be calculated correctly and also allow you to remove the date range condition in sore time range summation logic.

Comment: Sorry, should have included the complete query. I have specified the start and end date.


SELECT CUSTOMER ID,
NAME,
sum(if(DATE between '2012-07-27 00:00:00' and '2012-07-31 14:59:00',(Amount),0)) as 'Amount 1',
sum(if((DATE between '2012-07-27 15:00:00' and '2012-07-31 20:59:00',(Amount),0)) as 'Amount 2',
sum(Amount) as 'Total Amount'

FROM CUSTOMER_DATABASE
WHERE DATE between '2012-07-27 00:00:00' and '2012-07-31 20:59:00'
group by 1
order by 5

Comment: Thanks for your help Mike! Figured it out :)

Comment: However, facing another problem! When I use Time between '00:00:00' - '14:59:59' and '15:00:00' and '20:59:59', it works. But If I change the time to show amount between '21:00:00'-'14:59:59'(next day) and '15:00:00' -'20:59:59', 'Amount 1' does not return any value. Here's the query: SELECT CUSTOMER ID, NAME, sum(if(Time(DATE) between '21:00:00' and '14:59:59',(Amount),0)) as 'Amount 1', sum(if(Time(DATE) between '15:00:00' and '20:59:59',(Amount),0)) as 'Amount 2', sum(Amount) as 'Total Amount' FROM CUSTOMER_DATABASE WHERE DATE between '2012-07-01' and '2012-07-31' group by 1 order by 5

Comment: @Justus That is because `TIME(Date) BETWEEN '21:00:00' and '14:59:59'` would not be a valid interval.  The MySQL time function just strips out the time portion of a data time string without regard for the day component. It won't look ahead a day like that.

Comment: @Justus If this is what you were needing, you can accept the answer. It will help build your reputation to where people are more likely to help answering future questions.